# "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing" during API call with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I know this issue has been asked before but I'm having trouble really understanding what the issue is or exactly how to fix it. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm trying to mess around with [this](https://zelda-api.apius.cc/) API. I'm first just trying to grab the title of a game and display it in the console when I click a button. Whenever I click the button, in the console I receive:

> "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing"

as well as:

> "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

**scripts.js**

```
function getGame() {
    fetch('https://zelda-api.apius.cc/api/games')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            // appendData(data);
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });
}
```

I've tried doing variations like:

```
fetch('https://zelda-api.apius.cc/api/games'{
    mode: 'cors', 
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
})
```

Again, I know this isn't a new problem but I'm having trouble adapting all the other answers to my situation. I appreciate the help!

Comment: The CORS headers needs to be added at the server side.

Comment: When we are requesting same api call it is saying it is blocked by API so you have to enable cors at server level

Comment: We are getting data when we are sending on the same site

Answer (score 0):

If you check the error message from browser carefully, you will find that the header you mentioned should be in the **response** header. It means, you cannot control the CORS rules from the frontend code. This mechanism is used to keep the important informantion that api provides should only be get from the real site who owns the right dns.
You can check more details about this topic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Ok sorry if this is a dumb question but does that mean i’d have to set up a node server or something and define the headers there?

Comment: or is this something the creator of the API has to do?

Comment: There are some options you can pick to solve this issue, and yes, setting up a forward server is a common way. A backend server(made by nodejs or any other programming language) can get the resource from the origin site then forward the origin response to your frontend. @TheInternetDani